# iPhone Wireless Ad-Hoc Works only for some users

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

We've successfully been distributing our app to beta testers via Wireless Ad-Hoc (using BetaBuilder) for some time now.  However, some users (whose UDIDs are correct and added to the provisioning profile) get a "Unable To Download" "Done/Retry" error.  We've got the process working for some - what could be causing these users to have this problem?  iOS version & time-added-to-the-provisioning-profile don't appear to be relevant variables...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We ended up solving the problem (without figuring out why it worked), by using BetaBuilder.  We automated the process by using the ruby version, which we had to modify to get it all to work.  The automated, shinier version is available at https://github.com/dts/betabuilder .

Answer (score 0):

Are they using iPhone 3G and you built your app for armv7 only, perhaps?

Comment: Good thinking - but no - it even happens to my phone, which is an iPhone4.